# Designing (OAuth2) access token

Tags: security, oauth, access-token

We are planning to implement OAuth2 spec and are reviewing the "access token" implementation.
Looks like the specification gives a lot of freedom to implementors and we are looking 
for some best practices:

1. What to put in the access token? We want to strike the good balance between size and usefulness.
   I realize this is very application specific but perhaps there are some things that are really worth having.

So far we identified the following fields:

- User Identifier
- Expiration date
- Version (so that we can change the format in future)
- Client Identifier (i.e. app who requested the token)

Some additional attributes (e.g. password hash) would be stored in the database and looked-up during
authentication (using the fields in the token as a 'key').

1. How to secure it?

We are leaning towards securely signing the access token (HMAC) so that we know if it was tampered with.
The fields in the token would be then readable by everyone.

The alternative is to encrypt (AES) the whole thing and make it completely opaque to the user. This makes
it much bigger (in terms of bytes). It looks like FB is now using encrypted tokens (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/572/)

Any suggestions as to industry best practices?

Thanks,
Piotr

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can map the access token you issued back to a user in your backend along with expiry date etc, then it really doesn't matter how it's generated (other than it should not be predicable). The spec doesn't dicate the implementation detail.

The token can be a uniquely generated string mapped to user state in the backend, or you could encrypt user info and expiry dates etc into the token itself, in which case consider SWT. The SWT format defines exactly what you describe. It contains information in clear text about the user, clientId, scope etc, but then also provides an encrypted key to make it tamper proof. With a shared secret it's posible to validate the key even if it's generated on another server, or by another party. They tend to get pretty big so not ideal for passing in the query string.

There are cloud based STS solutions which can generate tokens for you. Azure ACS for example can generate SWT tokens via an OAuth2 endpoint and manage all of the state relating to refresh tokens, expiry dates, and authorisation grants for you. What you save in effort in using this, you'll probably loose in figuring out how to integrate with it, but it's quite neat.